# Relationship between variables to show matrix equal to $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

If we're given that $u ∈ R
^{m×1}
, a ∈ R
^{m×1}
, v ∈ R
^{n×1}
,$ and $b ∈ R
^{n×1}$

and a matrix $B$ given by $B = uv^T + ab^T$.

What relationship between u, v, a, and b would make matrix $B$ equal to $0$? I'm confused as to how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at it component-wise. We get:

$$B_{ij} = u_iv_j + a_ib_j$$

Where $1 \leq i \leq m$ and $1 \leq j \leq n$. So the equation is $u_iv_j + a_ib_j = 0$.